# WPF XPS Document doesn't display images anymore

Tags: wpf, mvvm, preview, documentpaginator

I am using the code below for years but suddenly stop to display images. I made a short version to test it and explain:

There is an `UserControl` `XamlPage` which contains only two controls:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="My Content"/>
    <Image Source="/Images/flower.jpg" Height="100"/>
</StackPanel>
```

`XamlPage` is used in derived class of `DocumentPaginator` class:

```
public class Paginator : DocumentPaginator
{
    double pageHeight = 1122.52;
    double pageWidth = 793.7;
    Size mySize;

    public Paginator()
    {
        mySize = new Size(pageWidth, pageHeight);
    }

    
    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        XamlPage page = new XamlPage();
        page.Measure(PageSize);
        page.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), PageSize));
        page.UpdateLayout();
        return new DocumentPage(page, PageSize, new Rect(0, 0, 10, 10), new Rect());
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override int PageCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override Size PageSize
    {
        get { return mySize; }
        set { mySize = value; }
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow, only two buttons, one open new window which use the `XamlPage` control, another one which open the `Preview` window. The buttons are bound to `Commands` in the `MainVM`:

```
private void PreviewCommandAction()
{
    Paginator paginator = new Paginator();

    MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    Package package = Package.Open(lMemoryStream, FileMode.Create);
    XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package);
    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
    writer.Write(paginator);
    xpsDocument.Close();
    package.Close();

    Preview previewWindow = new Preview(lMemoryStream);

    previewWindow.ShowDialog();
}

private void WindowCommandCommandAction()
{
    XamlWindow xw = new XamlWindow();
    xw.Show();
}
```

The `Preview` window contains only one control:

```
<DocumentViewer Document="{Binding Document}"/>
```

And the `PreviewVM`:

```
public class PreviewVM : ObservableObject
{
    private IDocumentPaginatorSource myDocument;
    private XpsDocument xps;
    private Uri packageUri;
    private Stream docStream;

    public PreviewVM(MemoryStream xpsStreamDocument)
    {
        docStream = xpsStreamDocument;
        Package package = Package.Open(docStream);

        //Create URI for Xps Package
        //Any Uri will actually be fine here. It acts as a place holder for the
        //Uri of the package inside of the PackageStore
        string inMemoryPackageName = string.Format("memorystream://{0}.xps", Guid.NewGuid());
        packageUri = new Uri(inMemoryPackageName);

        //Add package to PackageStore
        PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);

        xps = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.SuperFast, inMemoryPackageName);
        Document = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }

    public IDocumentPaginatorSource Document
    {
        get { return myDocument; }
        set
        { 
            if (myDocument == value) return;
            myDocument = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Document));
        }
    }
}
```

So, in the `MainVM` the `WindowCommandCommandAction` method open a new window and display the `UserControl` `XamlPage` without any surprise.
BUT the `PreviewCommandAction` method open correctly the `Preview` window and this preview display only the content of the `TextBox` but not the `Image`.
No error message, nothing in the Windows Event Viewer. I say again that this was working for years until two days ago.

By the way is there any other solution to get the preview? I need to use DocumentPaginator to manage pages.

The whole test project is on this repository:

https://github.com/yannicklal/TestPreview

Comment: Same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833484/flowdocument-xps-with-windows-update-kb5020880-cve-2022-41089 - problem is discussed on github https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/7357

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Microsoft problem due to the update of december 13, 2022.

[KB5022083 Change in how WPF-based applications render XPS documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5022083-change-in-how-wpf-based-applications-render-xps-documents-a4ae4fa4-bc58-4c37-acdd-5eebc4e34556)

Then do a .reg file with this content solved the problem and can be easily sprayed:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Windows Presentation Foundation\XPSAllowedTypes]
"DisableDec2022Patch"="*"
```

**EDIT**

The problem is solved in these updates:

**For Windows 10:**
[January 31, 2023-KB5023366 Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-31-2023-kb5023366-update-for-net-framework-4-8-and-4-8-1-for-windows-10-version-22h2-4b1c0bd9-9041-4253-92d5-921eeebe628d)

**For Windows 11:**
[January 31, 2023-KB5023320 Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-31-2023-kb5023320-update-for-net-framework-4-8-1-for-windows-11-version-21h2-6f0630ed-5f53-4417-8494-66a8d940e799)